# Inclusive LLC / Cache inclusion policy in relation to flush&reload attacks

Tags: flush-reload

Why is there something like a cache inclusion policy?
What is the benefit of using such an inclusive policy for the cache layout?
I'm asking because with inclusive LLC there you would be able to evict lines in the private L1 cache of another core.
And this would allow us to perform a flush&reload attack.